# Amazon Web Services: How to add test request body for Mime Type application/x-www-form-urlencoded in AWS API Gateway?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I have connected API Gateway to my Lambda function using Post Method execution. The request comes from Form and accordingly shown request data.

In AWS, I gone to Post Method and clicked Test and on bottom i have request body textarea and i tried adding Request body as standard userName=<>&password=<> template but it is not working. When tried using JSON or other format it simply says media type is not supported.

//Request Data

```
userName=deep&passWord=deep@1234
```

//Response

```
{
  "message": "Unsupported Media Type"
}
```

I expect the output as call to Lambda function connected but now it is returning unsupported media type.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add the header

```
'Content-Type': 'application/json'
```

to your request to let the consumer (backend) know in which format your request body is carried. And then you can put the body in JSON format and you should not `415 - Unsupported Media Type`.